# Trabalho com Struct e problema em print, alterar o Struct e deletar um Struct

Tags: c, array, string, menu, struct

Tenho um trabaho da faculdade pra fazer que consiste em criar um struct de "Cadastro de Biblioteca"(codigo de catalogação, nome da obra, nome do autor, editora, obras doadas de cada area, numero de paginas) e menu, com opçoes de "Cadastrar livro, pesquisar por codigo de catalogação e area, exibir livros doados, alterar um cadastro e deletar um cadastro". Os livro devem ser divididos em 3 areas( humanas, exatas e biomedicas) e cada area abriga no maximo 30 livros. Ah, e o main tem que ser o menor possivel, usando funçoes pra tudo. Mas estou com alguns problemas...

-Quando dou print dos livros algumas informaçoes não aparecem ou ficam trocadas com outros campos.

-A parte do struct q é char nao é alterada, quando a opçao é selecionada

-Não tenho a minima ideia de como excluir um cadastro de livros ( no caso uma posiçao no array)

**MAIN.C**

```
//Grupo #x: Lucas Machado, Luís Felipe Zaban, Yasser Guimaraes.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "menus.h"
#define SAIR 6

struct Cadastro
{
    int Codigo_area;
    int Codigo_de_catalogacao;
    char Doacao;
    char Nome_obra[50];
    char Nome_autor[50];
    char Editora[50];
    int Num_paginas;

} livro_exatas[10],livro_humanas[10],livro_biomedicas[10];

int main()
{
    int op;
    op = Menu_principal();

    while (op < SAIR)
{
    switch(op)
    {
    case 1:
        Menu_cadastra_livros();
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 2:
        Consulta_por_area();
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 3:
        verifica_doacao();
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 4:
        system("cls");
        printf("\n***Alterar Dados***\n\n");
        Menu_Alteracao();

    }

    op = Menu_principal();

}
return 0;
}
```

**MENUS.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "funcoes.h"

int Menu_principal()
{
    int opcao_principal;
    printf("\nMENU PRINCIPAL\n\n\n");
    printf(" 1 - CADASTRAR LIVRO\n");
    printf(" 2 - CONSULTAR OBRA POR CODIGO E AREA\n");
    printf(" 3 - CONSULTAR OBRA DOADAS DE CADA AREA\n");
    printf(" 4 - ALTERAR UM REGISTRO\n");
    printf(" 5 - EXCLUIR UM REGISTRO\n");
    printf(" 6 - SAIR\n\n");
    printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcao_principal);
    system("cls");
    return opcao_principal;
}

int Menu_cadastra_livros()
{
system("cls");
int opcao;
printf("\nMENU DE CADASTRO\n\n\n");
printf(" 1 - LIVRO DE CIENCIAS EXATAS\n");
printf(" 2 - LIVRO DE CIENCIAS HUMANAS\n");
printf(" 3 - LIVRO DE CIENCIAS BIOMEDICAS\n");
printf(" 4 - RETORNAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL\n\n");
printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
scanf("%d", &opcao);

while(opcao<4)
{
    switch(opcao)
    {
    case 1:
        Cadastro_livro_EXATAS();
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 2:
        Cadastro_livro_HUMANAS();
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 3:
        Cadastro_livro_BIOMEDICAS();
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 4:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
    return(opcao);
}
return 0;
```

}

```
int Menu_Alteracao()
{
int opcao_alt;
printf("Selecione uma opcao: \n");
printf(" 1 - Alterar Codigo de Catalogacao\n");
printf(" 2 - Alterar Nome da Obra\n");
printf(" 3 - Alterar Nome do Autor\n");
printf(" 4 - Alterar Editora\n");
printf(" 5 - Alterar Numero de Paginas\n");
printf(" 6 - Retornar ao Menu anterior\n");
printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
scanf("%d", &opcao_alt);
system("cls");
while(opcao_alt<6)
{
    switch(opcao_alt)
    {
    case 1:
        altera_codigo_de_catalogacao();
        break;
    case 2:
        altera_nome_da_obra();
        break;
    case 3:
        altera_nome_do_autor();
        break;
    case 4:
        altera_editora();
        break;
    case 5:
        altera_paginas();
        break;
    }
    return (opcao_alt);
}

return 0;
}
```

**FUNÇÕES.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int exatas=0,humanas=0,biomedicas=0,contador_e=0, contador_h=0,contador_b=0;


struct Cadastro
{
int Codigo_area;
int Codigo_de_catalogacao;
char Doacao;
char Nome_obra[50];
char Nome_autor[50];
char Editora[50];
int Num_paginas;

} livro_exatas[10],livro_humanas[10],livro_biomedicas[10];


int Cadastro_livro_EXATAS()
{
if(contador_e<10)
{
    livro_exatas[exatas].Codigo_area=1;
    printf("\nDigite o codigo de catalogacao: \n");
    scanf("%d",&livro_exatas[exatas].Codigo_de_catalogacao);
    printf("Digite os dados de aquisicao da obra-doado(S/N): \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_exatas[exatas].Doacao);
    printf("Digite o nome da obra: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_exatas[exatas].Nome_obra[50]);
    printf("Digite o nome do autor: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_exatas[exatas].Nome_autor[50]);
    printf("Digite a editora: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_exatas[exatas].Editora[50]);
    printf("Digite o numero de paginas: \n");
    scanf("%d",&livro_exatas[exatas].Num_paginas);
    contador_e ++;
    exatas++;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\nLimite de livros cadastrados atingido!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
}


int Cadastro_livro_HUMANAS()
{
if(contador_h<10)
{
    livro_humanas[humanas].Codigo_area=2;
    printf("\nDigite o codigo de catalogacao: \n");
    scanf("%d",&livro_humanas[humanas].Codigo_de_catalogacao);
    printf("Digite os dados de aquisicao da obra-doado(S/N): \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_humanas[humanas].Doacao);
    printf("Digite o nome da obra: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_humanas[humanas].Nome_obra[50]);
    printf("Digite o nome do autor: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_humanas[humanas].Nome_autor[50]);
    printf("Digite a editora: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_humanas[humanas].Editora[50]);
    printf("Digite o numero de paginas: \n");
    scanf("%d",&livro_humanas[humanas].Num_paginas);
    contador_h ++;
    humanas++;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\nLimite de livros cadastrados atingido!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
}



int Cadastro_livro_BIOMEDICAS()
{
if(contador_b<10)
{
    livro_biomedicas[biomedicas].Codigo_area=3;
    printf("\nDigite o codigo de catalogacao: \n");
    scanf("%d",&livro_biomedicas[biomedicas].Codigo_de_catalogacao);
    printf("Digite os dados de aquisicao da obra-doado(S/N): \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_biomedicas[biomedicas].Doacao);
    printf("Digite o nome da obra: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_biomedicas[biomedicas].Nome_obra[50]);
    printf("Digite o nome do autor: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_biomedicas[biomedicas].Nome_autor[50]);
    printf("Digite a editora: \n");
    scanf("%s",&livro_biomedicas[biomedicas].Editora[50]);
    printf("Digite o numero de paginas: \n");
    scanf("%d",&livro_biomedicas[biomedicas].Num_paginas);
    contador_b ++;
    biomedicas++;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\nLimite de livros cadastrados atingido!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
}

void Consulta_por_area()
{
int i, a, b,cont=0;
printf("\n\nDigite o Codigo de area da obra:\n [1] para exatas\n [2] para humanas\n [3]        para biomedicas  \n Sua opcao: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("\n\nDigite o Codigo de Catalogacao:  \n");
scanf("%d",&b);
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    switch(a)
    {
    case 1:
        if(b==livro_exatas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao)
        {
            system("cls");
            imprime_dados_exatas(i);
        }
        else
        {
            cont++;
        };
        break;
    case 2:
        if(b==livro_humanas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao)
        {
            system("cls");
            imprime_dados_humanas(i);
        }
        else
        {
            cont++;
        };
        break;
    case 3:
        if(b==livro_biomedicas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao)
        {
            system("cls");
            imprime_dados_biomedicas(i);
        }
        else
        {
            cont++;
        };
        break;
    }
}
if(cont==10)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\nLivro nao encontrado!\n");
}
system("pause");
}

int imprime_dados_exatas(int i)
{
printf("Codigo de area:  %d\n",livro_exatas[i].Codigo_area);
printf("Codigo de catalogacao:  %d\n",livro_exatas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao);
printf("Doacao:  %c\n",livro_exatas[i].Doacao);
printf("Nome da obra:  %s\n",livro_exatas[i].Nome_obra);
printf("Nome do autor:  %s\n",livro_exatas[i].Nome_autor);
printf("Editora:  %s\n",livro_exatas[i].Editora);
printf("Numero de paginas:  %d\n\n\n",livro_exatas[i].Num_paginas);
return 0;
}
int imprime_dados_humanas(int i)
{
printf("Codigo de area:  %d\n",livro_humanas[i].Codigo_area);
printf("Codigo de catalogacao:  %d\n",livro_humanas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao);
printf("Doacao:  %c\n",livro_humanas[i].Doacao);
printf("Nome da obra:  %s\n",livro_humanas[i].Nome_obra);
printf("Nome do autor:  %s\n",livro_humanas[i].Nome_autor);
printf("Editora:  %s\n",livro_humanas[i].Editora);
printf("Numero de paginas:  %d\n\n\n",livro_humanas[i].Num_paginas);
return 0;
}

int imprime_dados_biomedicas(int i)
{
printf("\n\n\nCodigo de area:  %d\n",livro_biomedicas[i].Codigo_area);
printf("Codigo de catalogacao:  %d\n",livro_biomedicas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao);
printf("Doacao:  %c\n",livro_biomedicas[i].Doacao);
printf("Nome da obra:  %s\n",livro_biomedicas[i].Nome_obra);
printf("Nome do autor:  %s\n",livro_biomedicas[i].Nome_autor);
printf("Editora:  %s\n",livro_biomedicas[i].Editora);
printf("Numero de paginas:  %d\n\n\n",livro_biomedicas[i].Num_paginas);
return 0;
}


void verifica_doacao()
{
int i,j,cont=0;
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        switch(j)
        {
        case 1:
            if('s'==livro_exatas[i].Doacao)
            {
                printf("\nObra doadas da area de ciencias exatas\n\n\n");
                imprime_dados_exatas(i);
            }
            else
            {
                cont++;
            }
        case 2:
            if('s'==livro_humanas[i].Doacao)
            {
                printf("\nObra doadas da area de ciencias humanas\n\n\n");
                imprime_dados_humanas(i);
            }
            else
            {
                cont++;
            }
        case 3:
            if('s'==livro_biomedicas[i].Doacao)
            {
                printf("\nObra doadas da area de ciencias biomedicas\n\n\n");
                imprime_dados_biomedicas(i);
            }
            else
            {
                cont++;
            }
        }
    }
}
if(cont==30)
{
    printf("\nNenhum livro doado!\n");
    system("cls");
}
system("pause");
}

int altera_registro()
{
int i, a, b,cont=0;
printf("\n\nDigite o Codigo de area da obra:\n [1] para exatas\n [2] para humanas\n [3]   para biomedicas  \n Sua opcao: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("\n\nDigite o Codigo de Catalogacao:  \n");
scanf("%d",&b);
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    switch(a)
    {
    case 1:
        if(b==livro_exatas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("\nLIVRO SELECIONADO: \n");
            imprime_dados_exatas(i);
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            cont++;
        };
        break;
    case 2:
        if(b==livro_humanas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("\nLIVRO SELECIONADO: \n");
            imprime_dados_humanas(i);
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            cont++;
        };
        break;
    case 3:
        if(b==livro_biomedicas[i].Codigo_de_catalogacao)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("\nLIVRO SELECIONADO: \n");
            imprime_dados_biomedicas(i);
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            cont++;
        };
        break;
    }
}
if(cont==10)
{
    printf("\nLivro nao encontrado!\n");
    system("cls");
}
return 0;
}

void altera_codigo_de_catalogacao()
{
int novo_codigo, posicao;
posicao=altera_registro();
printf("\nDigite o novo Codigo de Catalogacao: ");
scanf("%d", &novo_codigo);
livro_exatas[posicao].Codigo_de_catalogacao=novo_codigo;
system("cls");
}

void altera_nome_da_obra()
{
char novo_nome[50];
int posicao;
posicao=altera_registro();
printf("\nDigite o novo Nome da Obra: ");
scanf("%s", &novo_nome[50]);
livro_exatas[posicao].Nome_obra[50]=novo_nome[50];
system("cls");
}

void altera_nome_do_autor()
{
char novo_autor[50];
int posicao;
posicao=altera_registro();
printf("\nDigite o novo Nome do Autor: ");
scanf("%s", &novo_autor[50]);
livro_exatas[posicao].Nome_autor[50]=novo_autor[50];
system("cls");
}

void altera_editora()
{
char nova_editora[50];
int posicao;
posicao=altera_registro();
printf("\nDigite a nova Editora: ");
scanf("%s", &nova_editora[50]);
strcpy(livro_exatas[posicao].Editora[50],nova_editora[50]);
system("cls");
}

void altera_paginas()
{
int novo_paginas, posicao;
posicao=altera_registro();
printf("\nDigite o novo Numero de Paginas: ");
scanf("%d", &novo_paginas);
livro_exatas[posicao].Num_paginas=novo_paginas;
system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Você até postou um pedido de ajuda com trabalho melhor do que o pessoal costuma fazer. Mas parece que muito do código postado não é necessário para o problema. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Além disto me parece que você tem 3 problemas não relacionados. O que possivelmente tornaria a pergunta muito ampla. Talvez seria legal separar os 3 problemas em perguntas diferentes. Ficaria mais fácil criar o código mínimo, completo verificável e ajudaria as pessoas te ajudarem objetivamente. Vamos ver outras opiniões sobre isto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, cheguei hoje por aqui e ainda estou aprendendo...

Comment: @yasser Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Embora sua resposta tenha sido fechada, vejo que você começou bem. Fique à vontade para postar novas perguntas que o ajudem a resolver problemas específicos. Apenas evite perguntas "3 em 1" e com muito código, pois torna difícil para quem vai responder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando descobrir que seu programa não funciona por algum motivo, tente fazer o possível para isolar o problema. O primeiro passo geralmente é encontrar uma forma automatizada de reproduzir o problema, ou seja: fazer um programa que não dependa de nenhuma entrada do usuário e que quando executado mostre claramente o comportamento inesperado.

Com esse programa em mãos, você deve reduzir o escopo do seu problema. Use o princípio da busca binária para saber onde ele está, vá excluindo partes do código e substituindo por blocos que não fazem nada ou valores fixos até que seu problema suma. No fim você terá uma quantidade tão pequena de código que o problema será óbvio e é bem provável que possa encontrar sozinho. Caso não, pode sempre vir ao Stack Overflow por ajuda.

O que vejo saltar aos olhos em uma olhada rápida no seu código é o seguinte:

```
scanf("%s",&livro_exatas[exatas].Nome_obra[50]);
```

O seu `scanf` espera receber no segundo argumento um ponteiro de onde ele deve começar a por os dados. Quando você escreve `&livro_exatas[exatas].Nome_obra[50]` está passando um ponteiro para o quinquagésimo primeiro elemento da array. Como ela só tem cinquenta elementos, esse é na verdade o primeiro elemento da próxima array da struct. O correto é passar um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento, assim: `&livro_exatas[exatas].Nome_obra[0]`. Ou melhor ainda, meramente passar a array: `livro_exatas[exatas].Nome_obra`. Quando se usa uma array em um contexto que se espera um ponteiro, ela *decai* a um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento naturalmente.

Outro problema aqui: o que acontece se o usuário digitar 70 letras? Lembre-se, na sua array cabem apenas 49. O `scanf` vai escrever dados em pedaços da memória fora da array e isso não é legal. A solução é especificar no formato um limite de tamanho para a string. Troque `"%s"` por `"%49s"`.

Fica assim:

```
scanf("%49s", livro_exatas[exatas].Nome_obra);
```

Não sei se existem outros problemas. Cabe a você testar e isolar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu um dos problemas já! agora só falta substiruir um string por outro e deletar um dos cadastros...